# Connect to Oracle Server from cloud Azure Application

Tags: oracle, azure

I am pretty new to Windows Azure, I want to migrate existing web application that connects to **remote Oracle server** and run it as a cloud service web role how can I accomplish this while windows azure has no Oracle client installed by default ? or in other words how can I connect  from within .net application to a 64Bit Oracle database server without installing oracle client ?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Oracle client long time back so some of things below may not be right. But here are some of your options:

- You could make use of `Oracle client for .Net provided by Microsoft` and add those assemblies references in your project. When you publish the project, make sure that `Copy Local` attribute on those assemblies are marked as `true` so that those DLLs get packaged along with the rest of your application.
- If you're using `Oracle provided client for .Net`, I remember we had to install that application on our web server. In that case, you could make use of something called [`Startup Tasks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180155.aspx) in your webrole and install the package when your role starts. You could either include the installer as part of your package and then install the software using a startup task.

Comment: but how do you install ODP.Net on an Azure web-site? Or you are limited to a VM?

Comment: The types in System.Data.OracleClient are deprecated. The types are supported in version 4 of the .NET Framework but will be removed in a future release. Microsoft recommends that you use a third-party Oracle provider. from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4ba345c-fb99-4645-b9d0-a9445e92fb55/connecting-to-oracle-from-azure